# Convert ePub to pdf ios

Tags: iphone, ios, converters, epub

I am developing a ePub reader and i am using a pdf reader for it [Code](https://github.com/hammerlyrodrigo/leaves)

The problem is how convert epub to pdf so i can use the same reader(Leaves)

Other option is Leaves epub reader version is available then its better idea...

Some code for read pdf file :

```
CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("BornToRun.pdf"), NULL, NULL);
pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
CFRelease(pdfURL);
```

Thanks...

Comment: I found this document helpful to this topic  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4168

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Th ePub file contains html or xhtml files with some xml, What you have to do is,

1, You need to decompress the ePub file (rename .ePub to .zip, then u can decompress easily).
2, Convert the html files to PDF. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882151/html-to-pdf-conversion-on-ios)