# How do I print the HTML formatted text in NSAttributedString?

Tags: html, objective-c, printing, webview, nsattributedstring

I've looped through my core data entities and created an NSAttributedString that has the HTML-style data of the tables I would like to print. I'm under the assumption that I'm supposed to somehow get this HTML data into a view so that it can be sent to be printed. I can't seem to make the connection here - and I'm trying to do it all programatically, behind the scenes. I've looked into WebKit and WebView, but don't they seem to be out of scope?

I feel like this would be a relatively covered topic but I can't seem to find much information on it, and the information I do find hasn't been particularly helpful. I would really like to be able to print off the data being stored as well as print receipts for customers.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Are you trying to display a HTML table on iOS? You could surely use WebView to display HTML - the Facebook interface is all WebView...

Comment: Oops I forgot to clarify I'm developing for Mac OS! I've been very confused about exactly _what_ to do with my HTML string, I would like something to convert it into the format with tables, etc. and then have the ability to print it and save it as a pdf.

Comment: Well, maybe these may help you (should also work on MacOS) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937851/programmatically-generate-pdf-from-html-on-iphone but it's no easy task.
Maybe it's easier for you to use Safari and print it as PDF?